# Question about flags in synthenic geometry

Tags: geometry

The book is "Projective Geometry: From Foundations to Applications" by Albrecht Beutelspacher and Ute Rosenbaum.

On page 3, the definiation of a flag is stated:

**Definition.** Let $\textbf{G} = (\Omega,I)$ be a geometry. A **flag** of $\textbf{G}$ is a set of elements of $\Omega$ that are mutually incident. A flag $\mathscr{F}$ is called **maximal** if there is no element $x \in \Omega \setminus \mathscr{F}$ such that $\mathscr{F} \cup \{ x\}$ is also a flag.

Then in example a. 
Let $Q$ be a point, $g$ be a line, and $\pi$ be a plane of 3-dimensional Euclidean space with $Q \in g$ and $g \subseteq \pi$. Then the following are flags:

$\{ Q \},\, \{ g \},\, \{\pi\}$;

$\{Q,g\},  \{Q,\pi\},\{g,\pi\}$;

$\{Q,g,\pi \}$.

Note before in the text it states: Two elements of the geometry $\textbf{G}$ that are related by $I$ are called **incident**.

I understand the last two flags listed; however, the first listing of $\{ Q \},\, \{ g \},\, \{\pi\}$  is where I have some troubles.

First, lets label the three flags as $A,B,C$ respective to the order listed.

Now, I get that $C$ is the maximal flag. I understand that any three elements of the set $C$ are incident with each other, and all three elements are in $I$.

I see how $B$ is also a flag, but not a maximal flag.  Each set has two elements.

Now for $A$  I get a bit confused.  Now the book states that it takes TWO elements for "incident".  How can $A$ be a flag?  How come mutual incident doesn't requre two elements but to have the propertiy of incident it does require two elements?

Comment: The three examples in $A$ are vacuously flags, since they contain a single element each. Also, be careful with "the" with regard to $C$. There are lots of maximal flags.

Comment: @TedShifrin First, I don't doubt the existance of multiple maximal flags.  Second, vacuously flags just seem troubling to me, mostly because how the property of incident was defined in the text.  Could you recommend another book or online reference I could read, along side this book, as to help clear up any misunderstanding of terminology?

Comment: Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra), I guess. Flags can have any length, from $1$ to the dimension of the vector space you're working in.